# Text displays on top of covering div in spite of z-index - Chrome & Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, yui, visual-glitch

I'm experiencing the strangest issue. I've been banging at this one for over an hour no but to no avail.

I have a div with text, with this CSS:

```
    z-index:  1;
    position: relative;
```

I have a covering dialog box (YUI) with this CSS:

```
    background: #fff;
    position:   absolute;
    z-index:    200;
```

The box slides down in an animation.

For some reason, the text is displaying over the other div until—get this—*I move the mouse outside the window.* Then it all works perfectly.

My best guess is that this is a rendering issue. But it happens in both FF and Chrome (latest). Any suggestions would be helpful.

-

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can you reproduce a fiddle of it?

Comment: Post a link to the page if possible... if you using a CSS framework, the issue could be subtle.

Comment: It's behind a login screen. I'll see if I can get authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I magically fixed this. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Buy explicitly specifying a `z-index` for a parent element, this solved the issue:

```
.yui-skin-sam .yui-dt table {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;         /* <-- added */
    position: relative; /* <-- added */
}
```

Comment: Yes, z-index on an inner element doesn't mean much if the parent element has a lower z-index (or lower stacking order) than what follows it.

Comment: Which is what I want. It seems the browser was unsure of which order to draw things so adding a z-index (in the parent) bypassed the glitch.